# Using an unique entity file for several xml files

Tags: xml, entity, dtd

For some purpose, I would like to create a unique external file containing entity definitions.
And once it's done, I would like to "import" these entity definitions into different XML files.

**ENTITY file:**

```
<!ENTITY e1 "<e1>child1</e1>">
<!ENTITY e2 "<e2>child2</e2>">
```

**XML file01:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root ANY>
<!ENTITY % myents SYSTEM "test.ent" >
%myents;
]>
<root>
    &e1;
</root>
```

**XML file02:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root ANY>
<!ENTITY % myents SYSTEM "test.ent" >
%myents;
]>
<root>
    &e2;
</root>
```

I would like to know if it's possible that way?

Thanks for your help,
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible and the example you gave is valid except for the elements `e1` and `e2` being declared. If you add the declarations for those, to either `test.ent` or to the XML files themselves, both `file01` and `file02` are valid.

For example...

**test.ent**

```
<!ELEMENT e1 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT e2 (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY e1 "<e1>child1</e1>">
<!ENTITY e2 "<e2>child2</e2>">
```